# Use php definition in string

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following definition in my config file:

```
{
define('SITE_PREFIX', 'yst');
}
```

I then have in another file:

```
$stmt = ulPdoDb::Prepare('log', 'SELECT screen_name FROM yst_twitters WHERE user_id=?');
```

I would like to replace the 'yst' in the second snippet with the value of 'SITE_PREFIX'

Is there any way to do this and if so how?

Thanks

Comment: Split up the string, and concatenate the constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just be able to concatenate the SITE_PREFIX variable into the string. For example:

```
$stmt = ulPdoDb::Prepare('log', 'SELECT screen_name FROM '.SITE_PREFIX.'_twitters WHERE user_id=?');
```

Comment: Great thank you! I have made that change and it is working perfectly. Much appreciated!